snapchat Bitmoji kit, after snaopchat login get reply "something went wrong" IOS app tsx Expo
We are doing a basic implementation of bitmoji into an IOS app.
When we click on authenticate with snapchat
It takes us to login screen
If we type in the wrong password, it asks again
If we type in the correct password, it takes us to another screen which says
"Something went wrong"
we can cancel and get back into our app
we can only get out of this screen with a full factory reset of phone
.......
if feels like this is a setup problem but everything in devkit is correct. It's like we don't have read scope on bitmoji kit, but Snap doesn't seem to have a permissions in their dev kit?
........
we expected to go to bitmoji screen, instead logged in and said something went wrong.
here's the code, ID and URI all match correctly. We are just testing so have secret ID built within the code until we get working.
here's the code if anyone sees anything.
import React from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';
import { fetchBitmojiAvatar } from './services/snapchatService';

const CLIENT_ID = '4b360313-3088-4723-9d4e-1d9f8d15bd0f';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'NOTHING TO SEE HERE';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'chatsmeow://oauthredirect';
const AUTH_URL = `https://accounts.snapchat.com/login/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code&scope=bitmoji:read`;

const SnapAuthScreen = () => {
  const exchangeAuthorizationCodeForToken = async (authorizationCode: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://accounts.snapchat.com/login/oauth2/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            code: authorizationCode,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
          }).toString(),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.access_token) {
        await fetchBitmoji(data.access_token); // Fetch Bitmoji avatar
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Token exchange failed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error exchanging code for token:', error);
    }
  };

  const fetchBitmoji = async (accessToken: string) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://kit.snapchat.com/v1/me/bitmoji', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      const bitmojiData = await response.json();
      console.log('Bitmoji data:', bitmojiData);
      Alert.alert('Bitmoji fetched successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to fetch Bitmoji:', error);
      Alert.alert('Failed to fetch Bitmoji');
    }
  };

  const clearSnapchatSession = async (accessToken: string) => {
    try {
      await AuthSession.revokeAsync(
        { token: accessToken },
        { revocationEndpoint: 'https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/logout' }
      );
      Alert.alert('Session cleared. You can try logging in again.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error clearing session:', error);
      Alert.alert('Failed to clear session. Please try again.');
    }
  };

  const handleSnapAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(AUTH_URL, REDIRECT_URI);

      if (result.type === 'success' && result.url) {
        const authorizationCode = new URLSearchParams(result.url.split('?')[1]).get('code');
        if (authorizationCode) {
          await exchangeAuthorizationCodeForToken(authorizationCode);
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Snapchat authentication was canceled or failed.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Snapchat authentication error:', error);
    }
  };

  const clearAndReopenAuthSession = async () => {
    try {
      await WebBrowser.dismissBrowser(); // Close any open browser session
      await clearSnapchatSession('<your-access-token-here>'); // Replace with actual token if available
      await handleSnapAuth(); // Reopen Snapchat auth
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error clearing session:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Authenticate with Snapchat" onPress={handleSnapAuth} />
      <Button title="Clear Session & Re-authenticate" onPress={clearAndReopenAuthSession} color="red" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SnapAuthScreen;



thanks for any help or if you spot anything
